# Tampermonkey match all ip's

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey, userscripts

I built a userscript. I want the code to run at x.x.x.x. eg.: https://95.216.60.147/ or https://1.1.1.1/

my code:
`// @match       https://*.*.*.*/*`

but this is not working.

Comment: To run on all pages you don't need any `@match` at all. To match all numeric addresses use `@include /^https?://(\d+\.){3}\d+//`

Comment: You can test your ``include`` regex on https://regex101.com/. Please note that ``include`` tag may be obsolete in Manifest v3. It's also recommended to escape "``\``" characters: ``/^https?:\/\/(\d+\.){3}\d+\//``